# SQL selecting rows by most recent date with two unique columns

Tags: sql, oracle

Using the following query and results, I'm looking for the most recent entry where the ChargeId and ChargeType are unique.

```
select chargeId, chargeType, serviceMonth from invoice

    CHARGEID    CHARGETYPE  SERVICEMONTH
1   101         R           8/1/2008
2   161         N           2/1/2008
3   101         R           2/1/2008
4   101         R           3/1/2008
5   101         R           4/1/2008
6   101         R           5/1/2008
7   101         R           6/1/2008
8   101         R           7/1/2008
```

Desired:

```
    CHARGEID    CHARGETYPE  SERVICEMONTH
1   101         R           8/1/2008
2   161         N           2/1/2008
```

Answer (score 161, accepted):

You can use a **GROUP BY** to group items by type and id.  Then you can use the **MAX()** Aggregate function to get the most recent service month.  The below returns a result set with ChargeId, ChargeType, and MostRecentServiceMonth

```
SELECT
  CHARGEID,
  CHARGETYPE,
  MAX(SERVICEMONTH) AS "MostRecentServiceMonth"
FROM INVOICE
GROUP BY CHARGEID, CHARGETYPE
```

Comment: Don't forget to alias the MAX(serviceMonth) field in case you need it downstream.

Comment: ok, so what happens if there is a row

101  N 1/1/2008

in the table?

Comment: you would get an extra row returned. Which is the desired result based on his requirements.

Comment: Added alias to the query in post.  tvanfosson - that would be a conditional that added to the result set, which is correct.

Comment: Sorry. I need to read more carefully.  I was thinking row that matched max date for a given charge id.

Comment: You might want to change the title.  It's misleading.

Comment: If I wanted to also pull the record id with it. How would I do that?

Answer (score 65):

So this isn't what the requester was asking for but it is the answer to "SQL selecting rows by most recent date".

Modified from http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Returning_The_Maximum_Value_For_A_Row

```
SELECT t.chargeId, t.chargeType, t.serviceMonth FROM( 
    SELECT chargeId,MAX(serviceMonth) AS serviceMonth
    FROM invoice
    GROUP BY chargeId) x 
    JOIN invoice t ON x.chargeId =t.chargeId
    AND x.serviceMonth = t.serviceMonth
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be compatible with views.

Answer (score 12):

I see most of the developers use inline query without looking out it's impact on huge data.

in simple you can achieve this by:

```
select a.chargeId, a.chargeType, a.serviceMonth 
from invoice a
left outer join invoice b
on a.chargeId=b.chargeId and a.serviceMonth <b.serviceMonth 
where b.chargeId is null
order by a.serviceMonth desc
```

Answer (score 11):

```
SELECT chargeId, chargeType, MAX(serviceMonth) AS serviceMonth 
FROM invoice
GROUP BY chargeId, chargeType
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select to.chargeid,t0.po,i.chargetype from invoice i
inner join
(select chargeid,max(servicemonth)po from invoice 
group by chargeid)t0
on i.chargeid=t0.chargeid
```

The above query will work if the distinct charge id has different chargetype combinations.Hope this simple query helps with little performance time into consideration...

Answer (score 1):

Demo at [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e5dff/8/1):

1. Classical way.

```sql
select 
    chargeid, 
    chargetype,
    SERVICEMONTH
from invoice t0
where t0.SERVICEMONTH = (
    select max(SERVICEMONTH) 
    from invoice t1 
    where t1.chargeid = t0.chargeid
    and t1.chargetype = t0.chargetype
);
```

2. Using window functions.

```sql
with w_o as (
    select
        chargeid, 
        chargetype,
        SERVICEMONTH,
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY chargeid, chargetype ORDER BY SERVICEMONTH DESC) rn
    from invoice
)
select
    chargeid, 
    chargetype,
    SERVICEMONTH
from w_o
where rn = 1;
```

It is nice to understand and be able to use both styles.