# Pull Rows That Equal Max Date

Tags: mysql

My table structure is below.  The ma_symbol and ma_date are primary keys for this table.

```
ma_symbol |    ma_date | ma
        A   2015-03-01    1
        A   2016-04-01    2
        B   2014-01-01    3
        B   2014-02-02    4
```

For each ma_symbol, I want to pull the rows where ma_date equals max(ma_date).  So the result would look like this from the above example:

```
ma_symbol |    ma_date | ma
        A   2016-04-01    2
        B   2015-02-02    4
```

I have tried to adapt the following example but it takes far too long to run.  This table has 5 million + records.

[Attempted Adapted Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038193/select-row-with-most-recent-date-per-user)

Comment: Please post the query you've attempted (after adapting it from the linked post). The query in the linked post is irrelevant. Post your effort to query the table; ;we can't tell you what you might do differently in your code when you don't include your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tbl t1 INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT ma_symbol, MAX(ma_date) AS max_ma_date FROM tbl GROUP BY ma_symbol) t2
    ON t1.ma_symbol = t2.ma_symbol AND t1.ma_date = t2.max_ma_date;
```

To run this query in your enviroment, modify `tbl` to your real table name.