# SQL Server: I have multiple records per day and I want to return only the first of the day

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have some records track inquires by DATETIME.  There is an glitch in the system and sometimes a record will enter multiple times on the same day.  I have a query with a bunch of correlated subqueries attached to these but the numbers are off because when there were those glitches in the system then these leads show up multiple times.  I need the first entry of the day, I tried fooling around with MIN but I couldn't quite get it to work.

I currently have this, I am not sure if I am on the right track though.

```
SELECT SL.UserID, MIN(SL.Added) OVER (PARTITION BY SL.UserID)  
  FROM SourceLog AS SL
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select row with most recent date per user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038193/select-row-with-most-recent-date-per-user)

Comment: I edited this slightly for SQL Server and this returns the first entry ever and I need the first entry for the day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use group by along with min to accomplish this.

Depending on how your data is structured if you are assigning a unique sequential number to each record created you could just return the lowest number created per day.  Otherwise you would need to return the ID of the record with the earliest DATETIME value per day.

```
--Assumes sequential IDs
select
    min(Id)
from
    [YourTable]
group by
    --the conversion is used to stip the time value out of the date/time
    convert(date, [YourDateTime]
```

Comment: Thank you.  I made a CTE and then joined them.  The other solution worked as well but yours was faster and I think it will be easier for others to understand if they look at it.  Thank you so much, and I will work on writing better questions in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach using `row_number()`:

```
select *
from (
    select *, 
        row_number() over (partition by userid, cast(added as date) order by added) rn
    from sourcelog
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thank you. That did in fact work and I will work on writing better questions in the future.