# Select only one latest message from every distinct sender in php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing a site and I need a way of selecting only one newest message from the database and show to the current user like in facebook.

When the user clicks on the message, then the rest of the messages (if any) are loaded. Here is the database query photo:

[image]

How do I make only one message from e.g sender `75e928ac97dd17360a7890d6` to be rendered to recipient `AmoloCaleb`?

**UPDATE:**
Thi is the sql code:

```
$stmt = "SELECT  msg,sender FROM chat WHERE sender IN (SELECT DISTINCT sender from chat WHERE recipient=?)";
```

Comment: provide the `php` code you are using to query the database

Comment: @kikuyu1 done that

Comment: So you want the latest message per sender? This question is asked endlessly on this forum. Occasionally, it's correctly answered too.

Comment: @Strawberry  could you please cite one because so far,all I've seen doesn't suffice

Comment: add limit and orderby to your query

Comment: Please see [Select row with most recent date per user](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17038193/2298301)

Comment: thanks @DhruvSaxena