# Select row with most recent date per user using Flask-SQLALchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the same question solved here, but am looking for a solution using Flask-SQLAlchemy or SQLAlchemy:
[Select row with most recent date per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038193/select-row-with-most-recent-date-per-user)

I need to print one row for each different user that has the highest id, so this example table would produce the following output:

```
id  user    time    io
1   9   1370931202  out
2   9   1370931664  out
3   6   1370932128  out
4   12  1370932128  out
5   12  1370933037  in
```

output:

```
id  user    time    io
2   9   1370931664  out
3   6   1370932128  out
5   12  1370933037  in
```

models.py

```
class Example(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user = db.Column(db.String, default=None, nullable=True)
    time = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow, nullable=True)
    io = db.Column(db.String, default=None, nullable=True)
```

my query does not find the correct row for each user:

```
result = Example.query.sort_by(Example.id.desc()).group_by(Example.user)
```

Is there any way to fix my query or translate the SQL solution to Flask-SQLAlchemy, Thanks.

Comment: What DB are you using? The linked Q/A uses MySQL, but is that true for you?

Comment: I'm using SQLite, but I'd like it to be compatible with MySQL after I'm done developing. Right now I have the linked solution working as a raw query, but I'd really like to do it with flask-sqlalchemy to keep everything consistent. Thanks.