# Query Error: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax When trying to join 2 Query into one

Tags: mysql

please find the below

```
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oDs9VD1T7ScSimA4RHwmzN/1
```

Hi,
if you open the fiddle, i added test data,

Basically, the end result i am trying to get is, only one row from each custome_id order by last_updated and communication_id =1
Example Bellow Query gives all record order by updated_at DESC, but i need to extend it  so that it works "Group by Customer_id" id  and only show one row for each customer.

> SELECT diary,customer_id,updated_at FROM `test` where
> communication_type_id=1 ORDER BY updated_at DESC;

the required result will be like this mark in bellow link

```
[https://ibb.co/qNJdsbb][1]
```

hope it make sense.

mysql version
mysql  Ver 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))

Comment: Please provide the desired result - although this appears to be a duplicate of the most frequently asked question under this tag

Comment: You aren't selecting anything in your last query and you should not be using group by without any aggregate functions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select row with most recent date per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038193/select-row-with-most-recent-date-per-user)

Comment: @P.Salmon  , the Required result will be mark in this image
https://ibb.co/qNJdsbb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this

```
select diary, customer_id, updated_at from (
  SELECT diary,customer_id,updated_at, row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by updated_at desc) rn 
  FROM `test`
  where communication_type_id=1 
  ORDER BY updated_at DESC) a
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: hi, thanks but it gives 
Query Error: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from (select from communication_diary ORDER BY updated_at DESC) AS x GROUP BY c' at line 1

Comment: what is your mysql version. window functions are valid starting with mysql 8.0

Comment: @Devirs
mysql  Ver 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))

Comment: then this needs to work.