# When using an aggregate function in SQL, will the associated columns be selected?

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have the following query

```
SELECT
  day,
  category_id,
  name,
  qval
  MIN(CONCAT(category_id, qval))
FROM facts
WHERE
  day = CURDATE()
GROUP BY
  category_id
```

Will the `name` that gets selected always be the `name` associated with the `MIN` record that is identified?

Comment: In a word, no. Depending on exact version, it will either cause an error (selecting a column that isn't part of the group) or pick one arbitrarily.

Comment: NO, please have a look to this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/435703/how-to-select-the-most-recent-set-of-dated-records-from-a-mysql-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely not.  There is no reason to expect this to be the case.  This is your query:

```
SELECT day, category_id, name, qval
       MIN(CONCAT(category_id, qval))
FROM facts
WHERE day = CURDATE()
GROUP BY category_id;
```

Although not identified as such, this syntax is MySQL.  You are using a MySQL extension because you have columns in the `select` that are not arguments to aggregation functions and are not in the `group by`.  These values come from *arbitrary* rows.  Here is some relevant [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html) concerning the use of the extension:

> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to
>   nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause. This means
>   that the preceding query is legal in MySQL. You can use this feature
>   to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and
>   grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each
>   nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each
>   group. The server is free to choose any value from each group, so
>   unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.

I believe this problem is fixed in MySQL 5.7, because 5.7 detects functional dependency.