# SQL command to find when a document was last printed?

Tags: sql, bids

I have a table of document names and dates when they were printed. Say:

```
aaa    2006-09-15
aaa    2007-09-15
abc    2013-08-12
abc    2012-08-12
```

After the command executes I need:

```
aaa 2007-09-15
abc 2013-08-12
```

I got something close to a correct output but it involved temporary tables. I'm trying to put this into Microsoft BIDS and it doesn't like me using #temp_table.

Ideas?

Comment: What does your SQL code look like?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL selecting rows by most recent date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189213/sql-selecting-rows-by-most-recent-date)

Comment: Are these one or two columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT doc_name, max(date_printed) FROM your_table GROUP BY doc_name;
```

Here's the fiddle so you can check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd156/3