# SQL Select record with the most recent date

Tags: sql

I want to select the record with the most recent date from an INNER JOINED table.

```
Select table1.field1, table2.field1 
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.field1 = table2.field1
WHERE table1.field2 = table2.field2 AND most recent date
```

How to do that in SQL?

Comment: Do you have any column to store date in Table1 or Table2 ?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of *every* one of the "Related Questions" shown on the right…

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL selecting rows by most recent date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189213/sql-selecting-rows-by-most-recent-date)

Answer (score 2):

```
Select table1.field1, t2.field1 
FROM table1
INNER JOIN 
(
   select field1, max(field2) as mdate
   from table2
   group by field1
) t2
ON table1.field1 = t2.field1 and table1.field2 = t2.mdate
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the TOP 1 record ordered by date (in descending order)

```
Select TOP 1 table1.field1, table2.field1 
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.field1 = table2.field1
WHERE table1.field2 = table2.field2
ORDER BY date DESC
```

I might not be what you need if table2.field1 is not a unique field.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your table1 contains a field called `date_created`

Try this

```
Select table1.field1, table2.field1 
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.field1 = table2.field1
WHERE table1.field2 = table2.field2 AND table1.date_created between '2012-03-18' and '2013-03-18'
```