# Find the most recent date in a result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, max, where-clause

I'm working on a query where I need to look at patient vitals (specifically blood pressure) that were entered when a patient visited a clinic. I'm pulling results for the entire year of 2015, and of course there are certain patients who visited multiple times, and I need to only see the vitals that were entered at the most recent visit. Another slight twist is that systolic and diastolic pressures are entered separately, so I end up with results like:

```
Patient ID     Name           DOB          Test              Results       Date
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1000           John Smith     1/1/1955     BP - Diastolic    120           2/10/2015
1000           John Smith     1/1/1955     BP - Systolic     70            2/10/2015
1000           John Smith     1/1/1955     BP - Diastolic    128           7/12/2015
1000           John Smith     1/1/1955     BP - Systolic     75            7/12/2015
1000           John Smith     1/1/1955     BP - Diastolic    130           10/22/2015
1000           John Smith     1/1/1955     BP - Systolic     76            10/22/2015
9999           Jane Doe       5/4/1970     BP - Diastolic    130           4/2/2015
9999           Jane Doe       5/4/1970     BP - Systolic     60            4/2/2015
9999           Jane Doe       5/4/1970     BP - Diastolic    127           11/20/2015
9999           Jane Doe       5/4/1970     BP - Systolic     65            11/20/2015
```

There are 26,000+ results so obviously I don't want to go through every single patient and see when their most recent results were. I'd like my results to look like this:

```
Patient ID     Name           DOB          Test         Results       Date
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1000           John Smith     1/1/1955     BP - Diastolic    130           10/22/2015
1000           John Smith     1/1/1955     BP - Systolic     76            10/22/2015
9999           Jane Doe       5/4/1970     BP - Diastolic    127           11/20/2015
9999           Jane Doe       5/4/1970     BP - Systolic     65            11/20/2015
```

I know the name and date of birth and whatnot would get repeated, but I'm mainly focused on the results column.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    pd.PatientID as [Patient ID],
    pd.PatientName as Name,
    pd.DateOfBirth as DOB,
    v.Test as Test,
    v.Results as Results,
    v.TestDate as Date

FROM PatientDemographic pd JOIN Vitals v ON pd.PatientID = v.PatientID

WHERE v.TestDate BETWEEN '01/01/2015' AND '12/31/2015'
    AND v.Test LIKE 'BP%'

ORDER BY pd.PatientID, v.TestDate
```

After looking around for other answers, I tried doing a `GROUP BY` and the `MAX()` aggregate function for the `v.TestDate` column in the `SELECT` statement (I was specifically referencing [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189213/sql-selecting-rows-by-most-recent-date), though it's for Oracle and I'm using SQL Server so I'm not entirely sure if the syntax would be the same). My query then looked like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    pd.PatientID as [Patient ID],
    pd.PatientName as Name,
    pd.DateOfBirth as DOB,
    v.Test as Test,
    v.Results as Results,
    MAX(v.TestDate) as Date

FROM PatientDemographic pd JOIN Vitals v ON pd.PatientID = v.PatientID

WHERE v.TestDate BETWEEN '01/01/2015' AND '12/31/2015'
    AND v.Test LIKE 'BP%'

GROUP BY pd.PatientID
```

Admittedly, I've always struggled a little with using `GROUP BY`. In this particular case, I get an error stating that I need to add the Patient Name column to the `GROUP BY` clause as well, so I do, and then it asks for DOB. Then the Test name. Basically, it wants me to add everything from my `SELECT` statement to the `GROUP BY`.

What's the best way to proceed and get my most recent patient visits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple method uses `ROW_NUMBER()` to find the more recent record for each test:

```
SELECT pd.PatientID as [Patient ID], pd.PatientName as Name, pd.DateOfBirth as DOB,
       v.Test as Test, v.Results as Results, v.TestDate as Date
FROM PatientDemographic pd JOIN
     (SELECT v.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PatientId, Test ORDER BY TestDate DESC) as seqnum
      FROM Vitals v
      WHERE v.TestDate BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-12-31' AND
            v.Test LIKE 'BP%'
     ) v
     ON pd.PatientID = v.PatientID 
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY pd.PatientID, v.TestDate;
```

Answer (score 1):

I shy away from window functions as Gordon used. A technique using subqueries can get job done as well:

```
SELECT 
    ID
    ,Name
    ,DOB
    ,Test
    ,Results
    ,[Date]
FROM
    Vitals AS V
WHERE
    V.[Date] = (SELECT MAX([Date]) FROM Vitals W WHERE W.Name = V.Name AND W.Test = 'A')
    AND V.Test = 'A'

UNION

SELECT 
    ID
    ,Name
    ,DOB
    ,Test
    ,Results
    ,[Date]
FROM
    Vitals AS V
WHERE
    V.[Date] = (SELECT MAX([Date]) FROM Vitals W WHERE W.Name = V.Name AND W.Test = 'B')
    AND V.Test = 'B'
```

Comment: Why? Have you compared perfomance of  row_number()  and  ..=(select max() ..)?

Comment: Nope just haven't studied them enough :) it's on the list.

Answer (score 1):

This is for MS SQL 2005+

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT row_number() over(partition by pd.PatientID, v.Test order by v.TestDate desc) as rn,
    pd.PatientID as [Patient ID],
    pd.PatientName as Name,
    pd.DateOfBirth as DOB,
    v.Test as Test,
    v.Results as Results,
    v.TestDate as Date
FROM PatientDemographic pd 
JOIN Vitals v ON pd.PatientID = v.PatientID
WHERE v.TestDate BETWEEN '01/01/2015' AND '12/31/2015'
    AND v.Test LIKE 'BP%') t
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The windowing function will not be as efficient as the NOT EXISTS clause. I would like to propose a faster solution that does not use a windowing function:

```
SELECT 
    pd.PatientID as [Patient ID],
    pd.PatientName as Name,
    pd.DateOfBirth as DOB,
    v.Test as Test,
    v.Results as Results,
    v.TestDate as Date
FROM PatientDemographic pd JOIN Vitals v ON pd.PatientID = v.PatientID
WHERE 
    v.TestDate BETWEEN '01/01/2015' AND '12/31/2015'
    AND v.Test LIKE 'BP%'
    AND NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT 1 FROM Vitals as v2 where v2.PatientID = v.PatientID
       AND V2.TestDate BETWEEN '01/01/2015' AND '12/31/2015' 
       AND v2.Test LIKE 'BP%' 
       AND v2.TestDate > v.TestDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Common Table Expression to achieve this.

```
        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#RecentPatientVitals') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #RecentPatientVitals;
    GO

    CREATE TABLE #RecentPatientVitals
        (
          Patient_ID INT
        , Name VARCHAR(100)
        , DOB DATE
        , Test VARCHAR(150)
        , Results INT
        , [Date] DATE
        );

    INSERT  INTO #RecentPatientVitals
            ( Patient_ID, Name, DOB, Test, Results, [Date] )
    VALUES  ( 1000, 'John Smith', '1/1/1955', 'BP - Diastolic', 120, '2/10/2015' )
    ,       ( 1000, 'John Smith', '1/1/1955', 'BP - Systolic', 70, '2/10/2015' )
    ,       ( 1000, 'John Smith', '1/1/1955', 'BP - Diastolic', 128, '7/12/2015' )
    ,       ( 1000, 'John Smith', '1/1/1955', 'BP - Systolic', 75, '7/12/2015' )
    ,       ( 1000, 'John Smith', '1/1/1955', 'BP - Diastolic', 130, '10/22/2015' )
    ,       ( 1000, 'John Smith', '1/1/1955', 'BP - Systolic', 76, '10/22/2015' )
    ,       ( 9999, 'Jane Doe', '5/4/1970', 'BP - Diastolic', 130, '4/2/2015' )
    ,       ( 9999, 'Jane Doe', '5/4/1970', 'BP - Systolic', 60, '4/2/2015' )
    ,       ( 9999, 'Jane Doe', '5/4/1970', 'BP - Diastolic', 127, '11/20/2015' )
    ,       ( 9999, 'Jane Doe', '5/4/1970', 'BP - Systolic', 65, '11/20/2015' );

    SELECT  *
    FROM    #RecentPatientVitals;

    WITH    PatVitals1
              AS ( SELECT   Patient_ID
                          , Name
                          , DOB
                          , Test
                          , MAX(Date) AS Date
                   FROM     #RecentPatientVitals
                   GROUP BY Patient_ID
                          , Name
                          , DOB
                          , Test
                 ) ,
            PatVitals2
              AS ( SELECT   Patient_ID
                          , Test
                          , Results
                          , Date
                   FROM     #RecentPatientVitals
                 )
        SELECT  P1.Patient_ID
              , P1.Name
              , P1.DOB
              , P1.Test
              , P2.Results
              , P1.Date
        FROM    PatVitals1 P1
                INNER JOIN PatVitals2 P2
                ON P2.Patient_ID = P1.Patient_ID
                   AND P2.Date = P1.Date
                   AND P2.Test = P1.Test
        GROUP BY P1.Patient_ID
              , P1.Name
              , P1.DOB
              , P1.Test
              , P2.Results
              , P1.Date;
```