# Query item with closest date based on current date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get the closest date for item no and price based on the current date. The query is giving me output, but not the way I want.

There is a different price for the same item and it's not filtering.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT distinct [ITEM_NO]
     ,min(REQUIRED_DATE) as Date
     ,[PRICE]
  FROM [DATA_WAREHOUSE].[app].[OHCMS_HOPS_ORDERS]
  where (REQUIRED_DATE) >= GETDATE() and PRICE is not null
  group by ITEM_NO,PRICE
  order by ITEM_NO
```

[image: Current vs Expected Output]

Any Ideas?

Comment: 1) You should include input (the data being queried) so the expected and actual output can be reproduced. 2) One hint: `GETDATE()` also returns the time and, based on your screen shot, your column only records the date (no time).

Comment: there is no input. i am querying the data with that code and getting current output but i want to get whats in expect output .i used convert to change getdate() to show only date. and still the same.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: `there is no input` ← By input I mean the data being queried (*ie. records in the `[DATA_WAREHOUSE].[app].[OHCMS_HOPS_ORDERS]` table*) , that's the "input" in this case. Without that there is not enough data to create an [mcve] which is needed for those that want to assist you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` window function to make it.

```
SELECT ITEM_NO,
       REQUIRED_DATE,
       PRICE
FROM (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ITEM_NO ORDER BY REQUIRED_DATE) rn
    FROM DATA_WAREHOUSE].[app].[OHCMS_HOPS_ORDERS]
    where REQUIRED_DATE >= GETDATE() and PRICE is not null
)t1
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Could you order by the the absolute value of **DATEDIFF**?

```
ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(day, REQUIRED_DATE, GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an iteration of the [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) problem

I'm not quite certain what constraints you're looking to impose

1. Largest Date
2. Most Recent Date (but not in future)
3. Closest Date to today (past or present)

Here's an example table and which row we'd want if queried on **6/3/2019**:

```
| Item | RequiredDate | Price |
|------|--------------|-------|
| A    | 2019-05-29   |    10 |
| A    | 2019-06-01   |    20 | <-- #2
| A    | 2019-06-04   |    30 | <-- #3
| A    | 2019-06-05   |    40 | <-- #1
| B    | 2019-06-01   |    80 |
```

But I'm going to guess you're looking for **#2**

We can identify we the row / largest date by grouping by `item` and using an aggregate operation like `MAX` on each group

```
SELECT o.Item, MAX(o.RequiredDate) AS MostRecentDt 
FROM Orders o
WHERE o.RequiredDate <= GETDATE()
GROUP BY o.Item
```

Which returns this:

```
| Item | MostRecentDt |
|------|--------------|
| A    | 2019-05-29   |
| A    | 2019-06-01   |
| B    | 2019-06-01   |
```

However, once we've grouped by that record, the trouble is then in joining back to the original table to get the full row/record in order to select any other information not part of the original `GROUP BY` statement

Using `ROW_NUMBER` we can sort elements in a set, and indicate their order (highest...lowest)

```sql
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY RequiredDate DESC) rn
FROM Orders o
WHERE o.RequiredDate <= GETDATE()
```

```
| Item | RequiredDate | Price | rn |
|------|--------------|-------|----|
| A    | 2019-05-29   |    10 | 1  |
| A    | 2019-06-01   |    20 | 2  |
| B    | 2019-06-01   |    80 | 1  |
```

Since we've sorted `DESC`, now we just want to query this group to get the most recent values per group (`rn=1`)

```sql
WITH OrderedPastItems AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY RequiredDate DESC) rn
  FROM Orders o
  WHERE o.RequiredDate <= GETDATE()
)
SELECT * 
FROM OrderedPastItems
WHERE rn = 1
```

Here's a [**MCVE in SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/495c0/11)

**Further Reading**:

- [SQL selecting rows by most recent date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/189213/1366033)
- [Select row with most recent date per user](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17038193/1366033)