# MS SQL managment studio - how to SELECT latest date FROM one table for each record in another table

Tags: sql

i need to know how do i select newest record from table based on date for each record from another table.

```
Select 
Zamestnanec.Prijmeni Prijmeni, Atrakce.Nazev nazev, Pristup.Pristupod Od, Pristup.Pristupdo Do
from Zamestnanec, Atrakce, Pristup,ZamestnaneckaKarta, Terminal
where Zamestnanec.ZamestnanecID = ZamestnaneckaKarta.ZamestnanecID
and ZamestnaneckaKarta.ZamestnaneckakartaID = Pristup.ZamestnaneckakartaID
and Pristup.TerminalID = Terminal.TerminalID
and Terminal.AtrakceID =Atrakce.AtrakceID
```

when ZamestnaneckakartaID has more records in Pristup, i want to display only the newest one in column Pristupod

Result should looks like:

```
surname | atractionname | 1.1.2000 | 2.1.2000 will not display
surname2| atractionname2| 3.5.2000 | 4.5.2000
surname | atractionname | 2.6.2000 | 2.7.2000 will display
surname | atractionname2| 1.1.2001 | 2.8.2021 will display
```

Comment: What database do you use, and can you provide a sample of your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using window functions. Here is an example:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 
      Zamestnanec.Prijmeni AS Prijmeni, 
      Atrakce.Nazev AS nazev, 
      Pristup.Pristupod AS Od, 
      Pristup.Pristupdo AS Do,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ZK.ZamestnaneckakartaID ORDER BY P.Pristupod DESC) AS RN
    FROM Zamestnanec Z 
    JOIN ZamestnaneckaKarta ZK 
      ON Z.ZamestnanecID = ZK.ZamestnanecID
    JOIN Pristup P
      ON ZK.ZamestnaneckakartaID = P.ZamestnaneckakartaID
    JOIN Terminal T 
      ON P.TerminalID = T.TerminalID
    JOIN Atrakce A
      ON T.AtrakceID = A.AtrakceID
)
SELECT *
FROM cte 
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Thank you a lot =) I just had to edit Atrackce.Nazev to A.Nazev and its works.

Comment: One more question, this solution is just for newest record, but i want to newest record for each atraction. 
So newest for person1 on atraction1 and for person1 on atracion2

Comment: The only thing you need to do is modify the Partitioning fields according to your requirement.  Assuming you have atraction field in one of your tables, you need to do something like this

ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ZK.atraction, ZK.ZamestnaneckakartaID ORDER BY P.Pristupod DESC) AS RN

Comment: A.Atraction will add colums with expired dates, that i dont want to, i want to just newest

Comment: Can you post some sample data?

Comment: yeah of course https://ctrlv.cz/QYSk

Comment: The screenshot didn't help much. Try this one after replacing the fields in the partition by clause with the correct field names and see if it works.

ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ZK.Person, A.atraction,  ZK.ZamestnaneckakartaID ORDER BY P.Pristupod DESC)

Comment: Thank you, but it not working.
well, i can send u whole database with data

Comment: I have seen in your reply to one of the answers that you are trying to group by  Prijmeni and Nazev fields. If that is the case, then those should be your partitioning fields. Try these two and see if you can get the result you are expecting. 

PARTITION BY Prijmeni , Nazev,  ORDER BY P.Pristupod DESC
--or
PARTITION BY rijmeni , Nazev,   ZK.ZamestnaneckakartaID  ORDER BY P.Pristupod DESC

Answer (score 0):

Try  `MAX(Pristupod)`

MAX(Pristupod) will give you the newest record

Comment: And where should i use it ?
I have just this select

Comment: this will give a n idea of using it with select https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189213/sql-selecting-rows-by-most-recent-date-with-two-unique-columns

Comment: same result 
Select Zamestnanec.Prijmeni Prijmeni, Atrakce.Nazev nazev, MAX(Pristup.Pristupod) as od, Pristup.Pristupdo Do
from Zamestnanec, Atrakce, Pristup,ZamestnaneckaKarta, Terminal
where Zamestnanec.ZamestnanecID = ZamestnaneckaKarta.ZamestnanecID
and ZamestnaneckaKarta.ZamestnaneckakartaID = Pristup.ZamestnaneckakartaID
and Pristup.TerminalID = Terminal.TerminalID
and Terminal.AtrakceID =Atrakce.AtrakceID
group by Prijmeni, Nazev, Pristupdo

Answer (score 0):

If the row_number function is available.

```
Select *
From
(
    Select 
      Zamestnanec.Prijmeni as Prijmeni
    , Atrakce.Nazev as nazev
    , Pristup.Pristupod as Od
    , Pristup.Pristupdo as Do
    , row_number() over (partition by Zamestnanec.Prijmeni, Atrakce.Nazev order by Pristup.Pristupod desc) as Rn
    From Zamestnanec
    Inner Join ZamestnaneckaKarta Karta
      On Karta.ZamestnanecID = Zamestnanec.ZamestnanecID
    Inner Join Pristup
      On Pristup.ZamestnaneckakartaID = Karta.ZamestnaneckakartaID
    Inner Join Terminal
      On Terminal.TerminalID = Pristup.TerminalID 
    Inner Join Atrakce
      On Atrakce.AtrakceID = Terminal.AtrakceID
) q
Where Rn = 1
```