# How to select the row with the most recent of 2 date fields?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks, for example, like this:

| ID | create | status | update |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-09-07 | 0 | 2022-09-07 |
| 2 | 2020-03-25 | 0 | 2022-09-07 |
| 3 | 2021-06-12 | 1 | 2022-09-07 |
| 4 | 2018-10-12 | 1 | 2019-09-07 |

I'm trying to select the row that has `status = 1` and the most recent date in `create` or `update`. I know based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/189221/6509816) how to do this with one date field (ie, selecting the most recent `create` field alone using `Max(create)`). But how can one choose the most recent of either? What would this query look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT ...
FROM a_table_that_looks_for_example_like_this
WHERE status = 1
ORDER BY GREATEST(`create`, `update`) DESC
LIMIT 1
```